# Disabling of an HTML svg tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, svg

When I use the following [attr.disabled] with a button it works fine.

```
isDisabled = true;
<button [attr.disabled] = "isDisabled ? 'disabled' : null"> Click </button>
```

What to do If I want to do the same with svg tag? The same way does not work.

```
<svg>
 <use [attr.xlink:href]="show ? '#arrow-top' : '#arrow-bottom'"></use>
</svg>
```

I need to disable the #arrow.

Also is there a way to combine cursor:not-allowed and pointer-events:none without css ?
Tried this and doesnot work.

```
<svg [style.cursor] = "show ? 'auto' : 'not-allowed'" 
[style.pointerEvents]="show ? 'auto' : 'none'"> .....</svg>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding css pointer-events: none; and cursor: not-allowed; ??

Comment: @Eason Lin
Yes I have tried that and it seems to be working. Wanted to know if there is any another way.

Comment: If you want to give svg a disabled attribute like button, maybe try giving svg[disabled] a default css attribute: pointer-events: none; And BTW, if you set pointer-events to none, css cursor attributes will not work. I made a codepen you can take a look: https://codepen.io/uu9924079/pen/PojpoaM

Comment: I would like to know more details. For example: 1. do you have an inline svg? 2. is the svg part of a disabled button? 3. if it's just an arrow have you considered an animation transform rotate?

Comment: What is the functionality of the SVG when not disabled. Is it/should it behaving like a button, a radio button, check box etc.?